# I am experiencing a handlebars issue (handlebars is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

So after I start my server, go to my local host, and either click the sign up or login button, I get an error popping up in my console saying 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined" I don't know what exactly the issue is. I tried re- npm installing it because maybe I didn't have it installed. The error that immediately pops up in the console before I actually click the buttons is this:

http://s23.postimg.org/bgbykf3qh/Screen_Shot_2015_12_16_at_10_02_14_AM.png

I also thought maybe it was because I put the script in the wrong section of my HTML file. However, I keep getting the same error.

Here is what my index.html file looks like.

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Wishes Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
        <h1>Wish List</h1>

        <button id="sign-up">Sign Up</button><br>
        <button id="login">Log In</button><br>

        <template id="status-template">
                <h3 id="status"></h3>
        </template>

        <div id="form-container"></div>

 <!-- LOGIN ===================== -->
        <template id="login-template">

                <div id="login-container" data-id="{{_id}}">
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username"/><br>
                    <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="password"/><br>
                    <button id="login-button" data-id="{{_id}}">Log In!</button>
                </div>

        </template>

<!--      NEW USER ===================== -->

        <template id="signup-template">

                <div id="signup-container" data-id="{{_id}}">
                    <input type-"text" id="username" placeholder="username"/></br>
                    <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="password"/></br>
                    <input type="text" data-id="{{_id}}">Register!</button>
                </div>

        </template> 


<!--    NEW WISH ======================= -->

        <template id="new-wish-template"> 

                <div id="new_wish-container" data-id="{{_id}}">
                    <input type="text" id="wish" placeholder="make a wish"/><br>
                    <button id="make-wish" data-id="{{_id}}">Create Wish!</button>
                </div> 

        </template> 



        <button id="logout">Logout</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0 4/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.0.4/js.cookie.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is what my app.js file looks like.

```
console.log('app.js');

$(function() {

    $('#sign-up').click(signUpForm);
    $('#login').click(loginForm);
    $('#logout').click(delCookie).hide();

    if( Cookies.get('loggedinId') != undefined ) {
        wishForm();
    };

});

var formContainer = $('#form-container');

//LOGIN ==============================
    var loginForm = function() {
        console.log('showing login form'); 
        $('#sign-up').hide();
        $('#login').hide();

    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#login-template').html());
    formContainer.append(template);

    $('#login-button').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        loginPost()

    });
};

var loginPost = function() {
    user = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.username+"login successful");

        user = Cookies.get("loggedinId");

        wishForm()

     });
};

//LOG OUT =========================
var delCookie = function() {

    Cookies.remove('loggedinId');

    loginForm();


};


//NEW USER =========================
var signUpForm = function() {
    console.log('showing sign up form');
    $('#sign-up').hide();

    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#signup-template').html());
    formContainer.append(template);

    $('#register').click(function(){
        console.log('clicked register');
        newUser();
    });
};

var newUser = function() {
    user = { 
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
    };

    console.log(user);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/users",
        method: "POST",
        data: user
    }).done(function(data){
            wishForm();
    });
    user = Cookies.get(user.username);
};

var wishForm = function() {
    console.log('showing wish form');
    $('#sign-up').hide();
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#logout').show();
    formContainer.empty();

    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#new-wish-template').html());
    formContainer.append(template);   

    $('#make-wish').click(function() {
        console.log('clicked make wish');
        newWish();
    });
};

    var newWish = function() { 
        console.log('showing wish form');

        var wish = {
            content: $('#wish').
```

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: You have a space in the URL: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0 **HERE** 4/handlebars.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Typo.
Try:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js
```

Instead of:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0 4/handlebars.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading .js which path is `error 404`. Do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.0.4/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

More information about [Handlebars CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js/)